# Changing the font style for UISearchBar cancel button

Tags: swift

I am trying to change the font of the UISearchBar cancel button to 'OpenSans' but I am unable to access any properties. I can only change the tint color of UISearchBar, which changes the color of the search bar cancel button text & search bar UITextField cursor color:

```
searchBar.tintColor = UIColor(red: 187.0/255.0, green: 187.0/255.0, blue: 187.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this it worked for me.

```
 UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 15)!], forState: .Normal)
```

If you want to change the color as well add this to your array of attributes.

```
 NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()
```

Note: Made available in iOS 9

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have the swift equivalent for this would you?

Comment: Beautiful, man. Thanks a lot. You may want to note that 'appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses' is only available for iOS 9.0 >

Comment: @JLO I'm not sure what you mean, this is in swift.

Answer (score 4):

This is for Swift 3.0

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 15)!], for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 1):

swift 2:

```
if #available(iOS 9.0, *) {
     UIBarButtonItem.appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses([UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont.systemFontOfSize(15, weight: UIFontWeightLight)], forState: .Normal)
} else {
     // Fallback on earlier versions
}
```

swift3：

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "OpenSans", size: 15)!], for: .normal)
```

Objective-C :

```
[[UIBarButtonItem appearanceWhenContainedIn:[UISearchBar class], nil] setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                                  [UIColor blueColor], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextColor, 
                                                  [UIColor darkGrayColor], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowColor, 
                                                  [NSValue valueWithUIOffset:UIOffsetMake(0, -1)], 
                                                  UITextAttributeTextShadowOffset,
                                                  nil] 
                                        forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 4.2**

```
UIBarButtonItem.appearance(whenContainedInInstancesOf: [UISearchBar.self]).setTitleTextAttributes([NSAttributedString.Key.font : UIFont(name: "your_font_name", size: 16)!], for: .normal)
```